# How to upload a jupyter notebook service to be used by different users?

Tags: server, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab, mlops

I need to upload the jupyter notebook service that **will be consumed by several users**.

The requirements I need to meet are:

- **Isolation**: It is necessary to ensure that a user does not have access to other user's libraries.
- **Authen**: Whoever uses the service will need to authenticate.

*In summary, how do I upload a service similar to google colab?*

**NOTES:**

- I don't have a container orchestration service
- the environment I work in is a private cloud and completely on-premises.
- I have plenty of computational resources
- the solution needs to use only open source technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Jupyterhub](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub) and install it on your private cloud. This should give you both isolation and authentication.